# Vuex mutation does not commit payload data

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've got a simple VueJS application which uses a Vuex store:

```js
 const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      organisatie: {}
    },
    mutations: {
      loadOrganisatie (state, payload) {
         state.organisatie = payload.organisatie;
         console.log(payload.organisatie);
      }
    }
});
```

From one of my components I then load the organisation's data to the store as some other components on the page also need its data:

```js
...
created() {
   axios.get('/get/'+this.$route.params.orgId)
     .then(response => {
         this.$store.commit({
           type: 'loadOrganisatie',
           organisatie: response.data
     })
}
...
```

But the commited state of my Vuex store remains an empty object:

[image: vuexstore]

The `payload.mutation.organisatie` in the devtools is filled with the proper data. But the `state.organisatie` stays an empty object.

Comment: Can you quickly check that this is not one of Vue's quirks with regards to reactivity of objects by using `Vue.$set(state, 'organisatie', payload.organisatie);`?

Comment: If I  add that as my mutation, the whole mutation will not show up in the dev tools.

Comment: My bad, it should be `Vue.set`. Really odd though, because if I set up a similar test on codesandbox, it seems to work, both with `Vue.set` and with direct assignment: https://codesandbox.io/s/0m8x0vwzzw

Answer (score 2):

Hope, it will work great for you

```
mutations: {
      loadOrganisatie (state, payload) {
         state.organisatie = Object.assign({},payload.organisatie);
         console.log(payload.organisatie);
      }
    }
```